# Escaping Safety with Debug Statements

Tags: d, pure-function, debug-print, memory-safety

I know of

```
debug writeln("Some good debug message")
```

in `pure` functions but what about functions that I have carefully tagged as `@safe` or `@trusted`? DMD currently doesn't allow `debug writeln`'s in those because `writeln` and similar are currently `@system`. This is IMHO very frustrating. Is there a clever way to escape safety or do I have to temporarily comment out all my `@safe` and `@trusted` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I do is make my own @trusted debug_writeln.

```
@trusted void debug_writeln(T...)(T t) {
      import std.stdio;
      writeln(t);
}
```

Since this is @trusted, it will work inside @safe functions without changing anything. You can also just call it writeln and then don't import std.stdio or alias to force the disambiguation.

Comment: Great! I knew you guys had a solution ;)

Comment: I believe this is what we all do, for now. :)

Comment: this is bad if T has an unsafe to!string method

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution

```
import std.stdio;

void main () @safe pure
{
    auto str = trustedPureDebugCall!readln();
    trustedPureDebugCall!writeln(str);
}

debug auto trustedPureDebugCall (alias fn, A...) (A args) @trusted pure
{
     debug return fn(args);
}
```